# How to get all the tags in an XML using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have been researching in the Python Docs for a way to get the tag names from an XML file, but I haven't been very successful. Using the XML file below, one can get the country name tags, and all its associated child  tags. Does anyone know how this is done?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Comment: Look into the BeautifulSoup4 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using element tree's `iterparse()` and build nested lists of tag and text pairs. Conditional `if` logic is used to group country items together and leave out elements with no text, then `replace()` is used to clean out the line breaks and multiple white spaces that `iterparse()` picks up:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

data = []
for (ev, el) in et.iterparse(path):
    inner = []

    if el.tag == 'country':        
        for name, value in el.items():
            inner.append([el.tag+'-'+name, str(value).replace('\n','').replace(' ','')])
        for i in el:
            if str(i.text) != 'None':
                inner.append([i.tag, str(i.text).replace('\n','').replace(' ','')])

            for name, value in i.items():
                inner.append([i.tag+'-'+name, str(value).replace('\n','').replace(' ','')])
        data.append(inner)

print(data)
# [[['country-name', 'Liechtenstein'], ['rank', '1'], ['year', '2008'], ['gdppc', '141100'], 
#   ['neighbor-name', 'Austria'], ['neighbor-direction', 'E'], 
#   ['neighbor-name', 'Switzerland'], ['neighbor-direction', 'W']]
#  [['country-name', 'Singapore'], ['rank', '4'], ['year', '2011'], ['gdppc', '59900'], 
#   ['neighbor-name', 'Malaysia'], ['neighbor-direction', 'N']]
#  [['country-name', 'Panama'], ['rank', '68'], ['year', '2011'], ['gdppc', '13600'], 
#   ['neighbor-name', 'CostaRica'], ['neighbor-direction', 'W'], 
#   ['neighbor-name', 'Colombia'], ['neighbor-direction', 'E']]]
```

Answer (score -3):

Look into the built-in XML functionality of Python, traverse the document  recursively and collect all tags in a set.